# GDB: Force through an if statement

Tags: c, gdb

This is the structure of my code

```
if(someFunction())
{
  // Some code
}
```

where `someFunction()` evaluates to `0` most of the time

When GDB is at line 1 above, if I do `next` then `// Some code` will not be executed.

Is there a way to tell GDB to execute the code inside the `if` statement?

Comment: The code might not even exist if the compiler had a minimum of optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can jump to `// Some code` after stopping on `if` statement in gdb, unless `// Some code` was not optimized out, see [17.2 Continuing at a Different Address](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Jumping.html#Jumping). Assuming you stopped on `if`, you can:

```
jump +2
```

Answer (score 6):

I can just propose you a workaround. Have a temporary variable `int i=0` and then do the if as

```
if(i==1){
  //some code
}
```

When you reach the desired position with gdb. Set `i` to 1 using

```
set i = 1
```

and then your loop will be executed. Of course after the loop you will have to reset you i if you don't want it executed every time.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of that. I was hoping for something less hacky.

Comment: @Randomblue And having an `if(0) { }` statement in your code is not hacky already?

Comment: @HonkyTonk: Well actually my `if` statement is not so dumb; it was just for illustration. In real life I have `if(someFunction())` where `someFunction()` evaluates to `0` most of the time.

Comment: @Randomblue Then why not write _exactly_ that in your question? Why make us guess and spend time trying to solve a problem that's not the real problem? If you call a function and want to change the return value, you step into that function and change it there. When you then continue to step, you'll get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @HonkyTonk: Yes, that's indeed another solution. But even more hacky! ks1322 has the best solution is my opinion.

Comment: @Randomblue My suggestion, step into and changing the return value, changes no code and is done entirely inside the debugger. That's not even a hack. But I do agree that ks1322 provided a better, and easier, solution.

Answer (score -3):

0 means false, so it will not entering into if loop, use

```
if(1)
```